# how to stop setinterval function when an if statment is true

Tags: javascript, if-statement, animation, jquery-animate, break

i create a function that move element by 1 px and repeat it with a specefic time with setInterval heres The Code :

```
var Elementt = document.querySelector('.h');
var left = 0;
var speed = 100;
var limit = 10;

setInterval(function MoveByOnepixel() {
    if (left > limit ){

    } else {
        Elementt.style.left = left + 'px';
        left++;
    }
 }, speed);
```

The thing is when Left > limit is the  setinterval stops or going to repeat without stop ?

If it repeat how do i stop it when the if statment is true ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use setTimeout instead

```js
function MoveByOnepixel() {
    Elementt.style.left = left + 'px';
    left++;

    if (left < limit) {
        setTimeout(MoveByOnepixel, speed);
    }
}

setTimeout(MoveByOnepixel, speed);
```